# AlamoFire Ignore Cache-Control Headers

Tags: alamofire

Is it possible to ignore `cache-control` headers when performing a request/handling the response with AlamoFire?

Currently I am making a request as follows, and the server is returning large `cache-control` headers, when in fact we need to ignore them.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in // Do something
```

I know the correct solution is to modify the server response, but this is not feasible at this time.

Also, there are other requests where I do want to honor the `cache-control` headers, so ideally I would a solution that does not involve changing a global configuration of AlamoFire.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To ignore the cached data, you need to set the `cachePolicy` on the `NSURLRequest` before using Alamofire to start it.

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://my_url_path...")!
let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
URLRequest.cachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringCacheData

Alamofire.request(URLRequest)
    .response { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

> Setting the `cachePolicy` on the URL request always overrides the value set on the `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

By default, the NSURLSessionConfiguration cache policy is set to `.UseProtocolCachePolicy` which will honor the `Cache-Control` header values.