# can't disable cache in Alamofire (Xcode 9 - swift 4)

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I used [cannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342462/cnoon) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893800/alamofire-ignore-cache-control-headers/32937965#32937965) to disable cache when call almofire, but I still get old data every request, and the tableView not updated !
here is my code :

```
let myurl = URL(string: "HERE_MY_URL")!
var myURLRequest = URLRequest(url: myurl)
myURLRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

Alamofire.request(myURLRequest).response { response in

}
```

where is the problem ?

Comment: For starters the answer you posted a link of uses `NSMutableURLRequest` instead of `URLRequest`

Comment: @Malik , if I used NSMutableURLRequest , i get this error with request : Argument type 'NSMutableURLRequest' does not conform to expected type 'URLRequestConvertible'

Answer (score 1):

I added this code in viewWillAppear func , maybe it's not the perfect answer, but it works

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```